# How can you trim mp3 files using `ffmpeg`?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, mp3

Here is a Linux audio MP3 puzzle that has been bugging me for awhile:

How to trim the beginning few seconds off an MP3 audio file? (I can't get `ffmpeg -ss` to work with either 00:01 or 1.000 format)

So far, to do what I want, I resort doing it in a GUI manner which is maybe slower for a single file, and definitely slower for a batch of files.

Comment: An update.  Later, I stumbled upon the fact that ffmpeg is very picky about the --ss time format, and I was able to most easily trim off the first 9 seconds for instance by specifying -ss 00:00:09 (note that it needs all 3 numbers in hh:mm:ss format)  The version I was using may be old...
FFmpeg version SVN-r18709, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For editing mp3's under linux, I'd recommend [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net). It has a simple to use `trim` effect that will do what you ask for (see `man sox` for datails - search (press`/`) for "trim start"). Example:

```
sox input.mp3 output.mp3 trim 1 5
```

You didn't mention it, but if your aim is just to remove the **silence** at the beginning of files, you will find `silence` effect much more useful (`man sox`, search for "above-periods")

Comment: Thanks, awesome: it worked.  I ended up using the `trim` for simplicity.

The only downer was
`sox FAIL formats: can't open output file 'blah.mp3': SoX was compiled without MP3 encoding support`
--so, re-enter ffmpeg :/

Comment: That seems unusual. On my computer, it works without a problem with mp3s. It is a matter of build-time configuration. How did you install it?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz, if you install sox from a distribution repository you will most likely get sox without MP3 support (because of license issues). For example on Fedora 17: `no handler for file extension mp3`

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how to compile sox with mp3 support. No FAQ, no google, nothing. And the question was about trimming using ffmpeg...

Answer (score 6):

You could try using [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php), which can split MP3 and Ogg files and has the advantage that it does not re-encode the file, thereby avoiding quality loss.

Comment: I like it; thanks. It is simple, and yet has plenty of options... For example: here is the command I just used, which adds the split times to the filename:  `mp3splt "$file" 4.12  27.55.7` ... It allows custom output name formatting and multiple split points.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your time specifications start with hours.

To cite the [ffmpeg man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg):

> position may be either in seconds or in "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]" form

That means that when you choose the 2nd syntax only the `.xxx` part is optional. Else ffmpeg might mis-parse it as seconds.

Same goes for duration:

> duration may be a number in seconds, or in "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]"

Another pitfall is the ordering of ffmpeg arguments (e.g. the `-ss`/`-t` options for an input file have to come before the `-i` option).

### Example

```
$ wget http://traffic.libsyn.com/twiv/TWiV179.mp3
$ ffmpeg -ss 1:05:59.3 -t 00:02:03.9 -i TWiV179.mp3 -acodec copy \
     what_is_a_hmm_twiv179.mp3
```

With the specification `-ss 1:05:59.3 -t 2:03.9` you would get a different result (i.e. a 2 second long piece).

(Tested on Fedora 17 with ffmpeg version 0.10.7.)